# Alien meets president. The only thing the alien says is that the alien fleet will be there soon to wipe out the humans

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Trying to recall the name of a short story where a newly elected President is taken to a secret facility to meet a captured alien. The alien repeats the same thing over and over, something about how we are doomed and how his species's fleet will arrive in a short time and wipe out the humans. The president is informed that he has been saying that for many years, and that is all he ever says.

Anyone know it?

Comment: yes, but I can't remember the name. the president unexpectedly turns up to area 51 and demands to be shown around and it is there that he meets the grey alien. in the end the president agrees to keep it's presence a secret

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.
It is 'The Seepage Factor' by John DeChancie.

It appeared in the anthology First Contact edited by Martin H Greenberg and Larry Segriff
https://books.google.com.au/books?id=31ZZ8FrE4cwC
If you do a search for words like 'president' or 'base' you can see snippets from the story.